# CSS transition animation is not applied on inline svg <text> but on <rect> it works fine?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, svg

If you click the button it changes the position on both elements but only the `rect` has the animation.

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("stackerCurrentSectBorder").setAttribute("y", "0%")
  document.getElementById("stackerCurrentSectCurrShift").setAttribute("y", "10%")
}
```

```css
#stackerCurrentSect * {
  transition: .5s ease;
}
```

```html
<svg id="statusBoardSVG" ref="statusBoardSVG" viewBox="0 0 500 300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g id="stackerCurrentSect" ref="stackerCurrentSect">
    <rect x="30%" y="30%" width="31%" height="45%" rx="20" ry="20" fill="black" stroke="rgb(200,50,50)" stroke-width="1px" id="stackerCurrentSectBorder" ref="stackerCurrentSectBorder" />
    <text x="50%" y="50%" fill="rgb(120,120,120)" alignment-baseline="baseline" text-anchor="middle" font-size="80%" id="stackerCurrentSectCurrShift" ref="stackerCurrentSectCurrShift">current shift</text>
  </g>
</svg>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use a CSS transition, you need a CSS property to animate. The `<text>` x and y attributes are not. (Mainly, because they can take a list of values that position glyphs individually.)

In addition, x and y for the `<rect>` element have only been defined as CSS properties in the SVG 2 spec, which isn't yet fully implemented by all browsers.

You can easily use a `transform` property instead. But you must set the style property, not the attribute, because the attribute does not take unit identifiers (yet):

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("stackerCurrentSectBorder").style.transform = "translateY(-30%)"
  document.getElementById("stackerCurrentSectCurrShift").style.transform = "translateY(-40%)"
}
```

```css
#stackerCurrentSect * {
  transition: .5s ease;
}
```

```html
<svg id="statusBoardSVG" ref="statusBoardSVG" viewBox="0 0 500 300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g id="stackerCurrentSect" ref="stackerCurrentSect">
    <rect x="30%" y="30%" width="31%" height="45%" rx="20" ry="20" fill="black" stroke="rgb(200,50,50)" stroke-width="1px" id="stackerCurrentSectBorder" ref="stackerCurrentSectBorder" />
    <text x="50%" y="50%" fill="rgb(120,120,120)" alignment-baseline="baseline" text-anchor="middle" font-size="80%" id="stackerCurrentSectCurrShift" ref="stackerCurrentSectCurrShift">current shift</text>
  </g>
</svg>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```